# cons operator in case statements in Scala

Tags: scala

So I read about right-associative operators like the cons operator in Scala. I'm wondering why they work in case statements. It seems like you can pattern match using the cons statement here?

```
def findKth1[A](k:Int, l:List[A]):A = (k, l) match {
    case (0, h::_) => h
    case(k, _::tail) if k > 0 => findKth1(k - 1, tail)
    case _ => throw new NoSuchElementException
}

findKth1(2, List(3,4,5,6))  

res1: Int = 5
```

What is the placeholder doing here? I've only seen placeholders used in functions like this: `<SomeList>.map(_.doThing)`. Is it the same concept?

The only difference with `::` and `:::` is that `:::` is used for 2 Lists right?

Comment: What do you mean by "placeholder" exactly? `_` ? That just means you don't actually want to bind what would go there to an actual named binding. The first case there is matching only on the head; the second is matching only on the tail, and the last case is the default case.

Comment: Is this pattern matching on a tuple actually?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What are all the uses of an underscore in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8000903/what-are-all-the-uses-of-an-underscore-in-scala)

Comment: @Jwan622 yes. Looks like it. I can't edit my original comment but "only on the head" was referring to the 2nd element in the tuple.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**tl;dr** It isn't pattern matching the operator, it's pattern matching a case class called `::`

There are a couple of things happening at the same time. First of all, there may be a bit of confusion, because `::` is a method on List:

```
val x: List[Int] = 1 :: 2 :: 3 :: Nil
```

But there is *also* a `case class ::` that, according to the docs is:

```
A non empty list characterized by a head and a tail.
```

[More info here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19426548/is-cons-a-method-or-a-class)

Scala's case classes automatically come with extractor methods(`unapply`), which allow pattern matching, as in `case User(name, age) => ...`.

You are also allowed to use the case class name in an *infix* position (although you shouldn't do so, except when the case class is used like an operator, such as in this case). So `case head :: tail => ...` is the same as `case ::(head, tail) => ...`. [More info here](https://danielwestheide.com/blog/2012/11/21/the-neophytes-guide-to-scala-part-1-extractors.html)

When pattern matching, you can use `_` to mean that there will be a value there, but you don't care about it, so you aren't providing it a name.

So the three cases you provided are roughly:

- A tuple where the first value is 0, and the second value is a list with a head to be called `h`, and a tail which we will ignore.
- A tuple with some integer to be called `k`, and a list with a head that we don't care about, and a tail, which we will call `tail`. Also, `k` must be greater than 0
- Anything else, then throw a NoSuchElementException

Comment: quick question, I didn't realize the case statements here were the same thing as case classes...

Comment: yeah, the `case` keyword having multiple uses _can_ be a little confusing, but it looks good when you are using it to match on a case class.